# Any big sites using Client Side XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, frameworks

Lately, I've been pondering the somewhat non-mainstream architecture of building raw XML on the server side, and then using an XSLT stylesheet on the client to transform the XML into the full UI.  Of course, a fallback mechanism would have to exist if the client was not capable of client side XSLT, in which case we'd just transform it for them on the server side.

I'm already intimately familiar with XSLT, and this approach seems to be a clean separation of presentation and content, completely forcing the data into XML, and using XSLT for presentation.

I'm also aware that this does add an extra layer of complexity to the application, which is just another moving part that can fail.

My question is: are there any big name or big traffic sites using this approach, and if so: what limitations/lessons learned did you take away from it?

Thanks Internet,
Zach

Comment: Two years later -- are you still using this technique?

Comment: No, I'm not. With a bunch of new (mobile) devices coming out, this isn't mainstream enough to guarantee that it'll work.  Doesn't look like WoW is still using this either.

Comment: They may have just moved it from client side to server side.

Comment: This certainly isn't the type of thing you'd be able to feature detect either, since a failing test for client-side XSLT would mean that you'd need to reload the entire page to do the transformation server side.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like other people have mentioned, Blizzard has many sites that are client side xsl. I would recommend avoiding client side xsl. It is a really cool idea, but there are many unusual bugs that you need to work around.

In Firefox, any javascript that uses document.write will destroy the DOM. Also, the noscript plug-in for firefox stops client side xsl. In both cases, the user will see nothing. There doesn't seem to be a way to detect this kind of error, so a fall back will not work.

In IE, if you have anything that does a 30x redirect to something of a different origin (going from http to https or crossing sub domains), you will get an error for violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You did not really violate the same origin policy, but IE acts like you did. For example, if you go to http://foo.example.com/login and that does a 302 redirect to https://bar.example.com/login.xml, IE will treat the xsl as if it came from bar.example.com and it will treat the xml as if it came from foo.example.com. So you will need to revert to something like a meta refresh for your redirects.

These are the things that I came up with off the top of my head. It is a neat idea, but be aware of these issues.

Comment: interesting, had no idea about that one. These are rare cases though. I feel client-side XSLT is the future. Handing the template to the browser and having them fill it up with data is how the internet should work. I love that blizzard uses it on most of their sites :).

But like anything clientside... there's browser compatibility issues (css, js...)

Comment: Do you happen to know if these bugs persist in IE9 and FF4?

Comment: I don't get it. How does document.write and same origin policy have anything to do with xslt? Those are JavaScript problems.

Comment: lightblade, the same origin policy also applies to client side xslt. The way I understand it, document.write destroys the DOM and replaces it with the contents of the the document.write call. I ran into this bug often when trying to use some JavaScript libraries. Both JavaScript and xslt operate on the DOM.

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't tell you in detail how it's implemented, but [World of Warcraft](http://www.worldofwarcraft.com/index.xml) is pretty big and high traffic, and their web site is implemented as you describe.

Comment: you can see the implementation detail for yourself: http://www.worldofwarcraft.com/new-hp/layout/layout.xsl

Comment: Try going to the page in Safari, then view the source.  It doesn't use the top level <page> node, instead has <html>.  The stylesheet prolog is still there, is Safari showing the output of the transformation?

Comment: @zachleat: The WoW site uses UA switching to determine whether to serve XML with stylesheet instructions or pre-transformed HTML. IIRC, only IE6+ and FF2+ are served XML.

Comment: Indeed, Blizzard's sites do this. Unfortunately, it works poorly in IE6, 7, and 8 because MSXML has the tendency to hang and deadlock when applying XSLTs. That problem has only been fixed in Win7 thus far.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any big public Websites that use client-side XSLT transform (well, except World of Warcraft mentioned by Joel :-). So I cannot answer your question directly.

However, from time to time I was pondering the same question myself, and I have a hypothesis that the number of such sites on Internet must be very close to zero. :-)

The short version of my theory behind this hypothesis is this: with the exception of some pretty exotic cases, provision of client-side XSLT option is simply not worth the trouble. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The company I worked at back in 2001 released a server product that implemented exactly the architecture you describe. We had very good success offloading the processing onto the clients. Furthermore, doing client detection using the HTTP user agent we were able to use the server side XSL processing to cater to very specific clients like Japanese cell phones. I think the sites/services/products that use this technique do it quite transparently to the clients. However, I think the trend lately is to do the processing server-side so that you do not have to rely nor test on the particular implementations of XSL for a variety of clients and you get support for some XSL extensions that you would not be able to use when supporting the vast majority of browsers.

I know I'm not directly answering your question of naming some big name sites, but I hope I'm offering something of value to the problem. So, basically my point is that unless the performance saving of doing your template processing is more valuable than having to QA, support and development for three or four browsers without extensions, then you should stick with server-side processing.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently running a few minor pages with client side XSLT, all in swedish though (lillemanfestivalen.se, resihop.nu and beta projects). My biggest concern were that google did not index my pages content, just the XML without the transformation. However, since I launched resihop.nu a week ago, it shows up on google **with** transformation! :D

Now my other concern is facebook and other social sites, that do not understand how to handle it. I still, however, think the up sides are greater than the down sides. The fabulous speed and separation I get is awsome. And with resihop.nu, I dont even develop a separate API, I just point developers to the site itself. (More work will be needed there to make it good though)

Comment: I've launched a few more, little larger sites with client side XSLT now. And it seems that Google actually strikes down hard on this when they find it. :(

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Elijah's answer. I think that using client side XSLT is a difficult job. You have to do a lot of QA for it. But whereas with server side, you don't that QA. You have to take care of all type of clients and possibilities while using client side. There may be a possibility that your code may break while using client side XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

I may be biased when I say this, but working on a web based app that does this, I hate it.  The only reason it is even viable is because the clients are only IE6+.  Even then, there are issues with it.  I find XSLT to be very difficult and would suggest if you are going to do this to get a good tool for debugging and editing XSLT.  Why not use JSON and jquery?  Must more standard and less client side variability.