# Current state of client-side XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Last I heard, Blizzard was one of the few companies to put client-side XSLT into practice (2008). Is this still the case in 2011, or are more people now exploring this technique in production?

It seems that modern browsers (IE9, FF4, Chrome) and client processing power are primed to exploit this standard for tangible savings in server CPU power and bandwidth on large scale properties. Am I missing something?

The negative aspects I'm aware of include

- additional rendering time
- additional assets required on uncached page load
- additional layer of complexity
- noticably less developer experience than server-side template techniques

The benefits I perceive include

- template composition offloaded on the client
- caching of common template fragments offloaded on the client
- logical separation of document structure and data
- well-documented web standard supported by all modern browsers

Finally, although I know it's impossible to predict the future, I am curious to know opinions on whether or not client-side XSLT's day will come. With interest in HTML5 driving users to upgrade their browsers and developers to explore new techniques, I'm eager to see what develops.

Thanks in advance,

Casey

Edit:

Any insight into how transformed XML is viewed by Google and the ramifications it has on SEO is appreciated too.

Comment: You wrote: *I would say yes. How about you?* This could be taken as subjective and argumentative. If want an up today answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274290/any-big-sites-using-client-side-xslt, you should add a bounty on that

Comment: Good point Alejandro -- I've eliminated my personal thoughts now that they are documented in your comment :) I've seen that article you linked (I posted a few comments before creating my own) but I was not aware I could start bounties for other people's questions, or questions that already have accepted answers. I'll consider that approach next time. Thanks!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for facts and recent developments. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be somehow lost in translation, but I guess SEO issues is the main reason, preventing a lot of people of using client-side XSLT.

I'm not aware of search robots, capable of parsing application/xml instead of plain html or even flash.

Still it's a good practice (mail.yandex.ru is a notable example indeed) for highly loaded web-apps to use XSLT partially on the client, because traffic is large and SEO-friendliness isn't necessary.

Comment: Interesting, I thought that Google transformed the XML. If this is not the case then that is a nonstarter

Comment: I would love to see more info from someone familiar with search systems. My worries can be not up-to-date.

Comment: And don't forget that Google is not the only one. In a lot of countries it doesn't have even a leading market share.

Comment: What countries? According to this site Google is dominant everywhere: http://gs.statcounter.com/#search_engine-ww-monthly-200912-201012

Comment: Haven't checked these particular stats, but you should count China, Russia, South Korea and some more.

Comment: @Flack: Check how [Google](http://www.google.com.ar/search?q=site%3Awww.aranedabienesraices.com.ar), [Yahoo](http://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com/search?p=www.aranedabienesraices.com.ar), and [Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Awww.aranedabienesraices.com.ar) crawl my old XML/XSLT client side site

Comment: @Alejandro, thanks, checked. I guess my worries are a little exaggerated. But still, as a client, I wouldn't accept such risks without large sites' success stories. And, last but not least, I do believe that if you didn't choose boilerplate pattern, consequences could be different.

Comment: Google will crawl XML files but the important tags like title and meta description must be present in the XML; if you insert or modify them with XSLT the changes won't be picked up by Google. To me this is a serious pitfall and a reason to shy away from XSLT for now. I've chosen your answer for this reason. Thanks!

Comment: One other thing to mention (saw this on another similar SO question) -- www.sketchers.com is using client-side XSLT

Comment: Hi Flack, Aren't the same considerations about challenging SEO also in force for client-side applications (such as SPA), that get their data from the servers via AJAX (probably serialized as JSON) and then perform dynamic data binding to produce the final markup? Examples are sites built with KO, and recently, with Angular.

Comment: Hi, Dimitre. You should consider using JS both on server and client. That way you could use the same templates and thus be able to serve content in a different way. E.g., you render templates on server for the first time user gets on site, and then just rerender parts you need on client. So you serve plain html for robots and incremental updates for users browsing more than one page.

Answer (score 3):

I use client-side XSLT on [kulesh.info](http://kulesh.info/html). I haven't found any differences in IE 6–9, Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. XSLT transformation happens very fast. I haven't done any speed measurement, but I don't see any differences comparing to pure HTML version (even on first generation of iPod Touch).

[mail.yandex.ru](http://mail.yandex.ru/) (big mail provider in Russia) is also using XSLT on client-side.

Answer (score 3):

> Last I heard, Blizzard was one of the
>   few companies to put client-side XSLT
>   into practice (2008). Is this still
>   the case in 2011, or are more people
>   now exploring this technique in
>   production?

Here are some examples:

1. **[Jenni Tennison's site](http://www.jenitennison.com/index.xml) is completely XSLT-client-site driven** and has been so for years.
2. **This commercial website is totally client-side XSLT driven: http://www.skechers.com/**
3. **We already have an implementation of XQuery in the browser: [XQIB](http://www.xqib.org/)**
4. **Michael Kay has blogged about his attempt to produce [XSLT 2.0 in the browser](http://saxonica.blogharbor.com/blog/_archives/2010/11/16/4681337.html)** and there would be something working soon.

Some people argue that XSLT isn't designed for "programming in the large" -- for example it lacks any separate compilation capabilities. Let's hope that the coming XSLT 3.0 will change this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the XSLT stuff on the web is there are so many other things out there that can be used in place of it that are easier on the developers.  I can never really see XSLT taking hold on the web in the form you are describing, in fact I believe Blizzard actually pulled the client side XSLT translations from their sites when they recently did some redesigns to consolidate their brands.

Trust me though, I wish it would, I wrote a solution for a company I worked for in the past that used XSLT translations for all their front end templating.  It didn't use client side translations because this was in 2005, when there was still a large market share of browsers that didn't support client side XSLT.  One of the biggest issues we had when working with that system was finding developers that could help work on it.  And when you found someone who could work with it they'd butcher a lot of the templating because XSLT development is a different beast than any other templating language out there.

While the benefits of using XSLT are tremendous ( do a google search for symphony, a great cms that utilizes xslt as it's templating system ) I don't see it taking much more hold for front end development.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, and for pointing out the Blizzard refresh -- glad I got over that WoW addiction. I'd be really interested to know why they strayed away from it; too bad they don't have a dev blog. I've seen Symphony CMS and it seems like a great idea -- if/when client side XSLT does become desirable, you'd be primed for a painless switch.

Answer (score 1):

When making a decision about XSLT usage, it usually comes down to a cost of developer time vs perceived benefit in CPU cycles. For a little customer it almost universally means: XSLT, if it exists, goes on a server side. There is simply not enough benefit in figuring out all the client issues.

If a breakthrough is coming, it will be on the big sites, such as: facebook, or google. On those, the CPU cycles offloaded to a client will make up a significant $$$ figure, enough to justify hiring developer(s), who will iron out the client problems. I would be watching those players to see if a change is going to happen

Comment: Yes, the big fish will definitely drive this change -- think of the benefits on a site like Wikipedia. I guess part of my question is -- what is preventing major players from doing this today?

Comment: @Casey: I don't know... I would imagine it's the same old "good enough" approach. Probably benefit does not significantly outweight cost.

Answer (score 1):

I made a XML - XSLT website a couple of years ago for a project in school and noticed a bug: Firefox doesn't support disable-output-escaping.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98168

Comment: Yeah. Discussed it lately http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492303/parsing-xml-string-using-xslt/4492361#4492361. AFAIR, it's not really a bug, because DOE support is not mandatory for implementers.

Comment: @Flack: You are right, that's not a bug. They didn't implement XPath `namespace` axe... But for real production stylesheet that should not be a problem.

Comment: @Alejandro, did they somehow explained the namespace axis absence? Because it looks like a blunder to me.

Comment: @Flack: between XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 there was a consensus into W3C on deprecating `namespace` axe.

Comment: @Alejandro, thanks, I did not know that. I'm totally stuck in 1.0 world :(